# Where can I find itemized list of earnings from S&P 500?

Tags: stock-analysis, standard-and-poors-500

I'd like to invest in the S&P 500. I want to know where the earnings come from. For example if my return on a share was $100, I'd like to know what percent/dollar was from which industry (ie. tech, finance, etc). Is this possible?

Comment: Like [this](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/portfolio/voo)? "Equity sector diversification" a page or two down.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, this is showing the percent shares in each sector. I'd like to find the percent earnings from each sector per share.

Comment: Percent of money in each sector, the absolute number of shares is irrelevant. But if you want earnings I expect you'd have to look at each company individually. Not sure what information you expect to glean from that though.

Comment: It would help me determine sectors that are performing well. I'd like to purchase shares of those sectors separately. I was hoping there would be a breakdown of earnings.

Comment: You can check the performance of [sector ETFs](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/list#/etf/asset-class/month-end-returns). Raw earnings numbers don't really mean anything anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. Partly it depends on your definition of earnings and return.  For equities (i.e., stocks and ETFs thereof), bear in mind that one's investment return can come in the form of price appreciation and dividends. Earnings, however, generally refer to the net income of a given company.  The two are correlated but not 1:1, i.e., $1 of net income (earnings) will not necessarily translate into $1 of return.

That said, what one could do is to find a list of the S&P 500 constituent companies and then go to their SEC filings individually and pull out their earnings.  If you had Bloomberg/FactSet/S&P Capital IQ/Refinitiv, this would be a fairly easy exercise, but most non-industry practitioners don't have access to these tools (check your local library, as I know some, like NYPL, do have Bloomberg, and if you're a student, your university will invariably have access to one of these services).